# Sympa attachments are zero length when downloading from a message in moderation

Tags: fastcgi, perl, attachment, sympa

I have an issue with the web interface for [Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/) mailing list server. If you try to download an attachment from a message that's in moderation, the file is zero length. The mime headers are being sent correctly.

The attachment is in the raw email, I can confirm this, as when the mail is archived the attachment is available, same is the case if you forward the message on to an external address. I have also found the raw email in the spool directory and confirmed the multi part message exists.

I am looking for some advice on where I should be looking. I am not a PERL developer, but have years experience with other languages. I can only assume that this should be a configuration issue. I am just not sure if I should be looking at the FASTCGI config or the Sympa config.

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated.

More info;

- I have a few different installations of Sympa on different servers and have the same issue on each.
- I am running an older version of Sympa (It's the current one in Debian 5) and it's not really an option for this client to maintain their own packages.
- This is only when you are moderating a message. All other times the attachments are not zero length.
- Max file attachments are set to 5MB, I am testing with a PDF attachment of ~80K.

Version Information

- Apache 2 + FastCGI
- Perl: 5.10.0
- Sympa: 5.3.4
- Debian 5.0.5 (2.6.26-2-xen-686)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turrs out this is a bug within Sympa and has been fixed. However didn't seem to make it into the Debian package. Have patched this manually. See [this](http://sourcesup.cru.fr/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3790&group_id=23&atid=167) for details.